# how to handle textview span style bold issue with langs having semi-characters(like hindi matra: ा ि ी ु) being seperated out?

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable, spannablestringbuilder, android-spannable

I need to style some part of text in a `TextView` like making bold etc. I'm supporting multiple languages but facing an issue when the languages have dependent semi-characters like matra in Hindi which are dependent on other characters. ex : `Hindi Matra: ा ि ी ु`. As soon as bold or some style is applied to them, they separate out from the connected character and form a word like this -> 'बीपी मश ीन' instead of this -> 'बीपी मशीन'

Adding code below. Please help find a solution for this.

```
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.text);

String keyword = "बीपी मशीन";
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(keyword);

spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 7, keyword.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```

[image: text after style applied]